# Shared layout priority

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `_layout1.cshtml` in `Areas/Book/Views/Shared/_layout1.cshtml` and in `/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml`.

Areas/Book/Views/Home/Index.cshmtl:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Book/Views/Shared/_layout1.cshtml";    
}
```

Somehow it stills show the content of `_layout1` in Root `/Views/Shared` instead of in the `Areas/Book`

Is there any priority when the layout view share the same name?

Comment: make sure layout path is correct. Layout = "~/Areas/Truyen/Views/Shared/_layout1.cshtml";

Answer (score 0):

The code as you posted it here should work. I am using the same successfully here.

Make shure the path is correct and the layout file is where you say it is.

Maybe odd, but what could cause this if the file is there:
If your APP is running with a differen user which does not have access rights to the file it could happen that the file "is not there" for the app.